# How to call one API with different paramet in Rx Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

This is function

```
fun deleteSingleVideoOneByOne(path: ArrayList<String>)
```

This is implementation

```
override fun deleteSingleVideoOneByOne(path: ArrayList<String>) {
        val apiService = RetrofitInstance.getApiServiceXMLForR2(
                Constants.BASE_URL_NEW_CAMERA_R2_4K_PRO
        )
        trackDisposable(
                apiService.r2NtKCommandExecute("6006",path)
                        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                        .subscribe(::handleDeleteSingleFile, ::handlerError)
        )
    }



private fun handleDeleteSingleFile(response: FunctionModel?) {
        response?.let { callback?.onSuccessDeleteSingleVideo(it) }
    }
```

above is my code i want call API for all path: ArrayList and  once it done i should get success message if any one fail i should get fail response i don't know how i can call once by one and get response at end so that i can subscribe it can any one please help me how we can use zip or flat map to execute api multiple time with different parameter  at end i should get response . please help me in this thanks

Comment: Question is unclear, also how does `r2NtKCommandExecute` look like

Comment: @Jemshit i want execute api call multiple time based on different parameter like different path

Comment: deleteSingleVideoOneByOne() supposed to return the result? You shouldnt have callback if you are working with RxJava

Comment: Thanks for responding @Jemshit I am facing challenge actually i have to call API 3 time one by one and once it done then at end i should get success  as string anything and if any time like 1st or  2nd time or 3r time api fail then it should return fail.